# Deleting hudi records with composite primary key ignores some parts of the key

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue, apache-hudi

I have a hudi table with a composite primary key made from two columns: `col1` and `col2` with the following configuration:

```
commonConfig = {
    'className' : 'org.apache.hudi',
    'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.use_jdbc':'false',
    'hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field': 'tx_commit_time',
    'hoodie.table.name': 'tableName',
    'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.database': 'dbName',
    'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.table': 'tableName',
    'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.enable': 'true',
    'hoodie.datasource.write.keygenerator.class': 'org.apache.hudi.keygen.ComplexKeyGenerator',
    'hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field': 'col1,col2',
    'hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.field': 'partitionField',
    'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_extractor_class': 'org.apache.hudi.hive.MultiPartKeysValueExtractor',
    'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_fields': 'partitionField'
}

incrementalConfig = {
    'hoodie.upsert.shuffle.parallelism': 20,
    'hoodie.datasource.write.operation': 'upsert',
    'hoodie.cleaner.policy': 'KEEP_LATEST_COMMITS',
    'hoodie.cleaner.commits.retained': 0
}

deleteDataConfig = {
    'hoodie.datasource.write.payload.class': 'org.apache.hudi.common.model.EmptyHoodieRecordPayload'
}
```

For each value of `col1` there are two records, with different values for `col2`. Something like that:

```
| col1 | col2 |
| ---- | ---- |
| x    | 1    | 
| x    | 2    | 
| y    | 1    | 
| y    | 2    |
```

I have a pyspark Glue script that receives `col1` and `col2` as parameters and deletes the relevant record:

```
sqlStatement = f"select * from {dbName}.{tableName} where col1='{col1}' and col2={col2}"
rowToBeDeletedDF = spark.sql(sqlStatement)
print(rowToBeDeletedDF.count())
combinedConf = {**commonConfig, **incrementalConfig, **deleteDataConfig}
rowToBeDeletedDF.write.format("hudi").options(**combinedConf).mode("Append").save(targetPath)
```

Problem is that although only one row is returned in the dataframe (as expected), when I apply the deletion it deletes both rows with the same `col1` value, although only one of them is returned in the dataframe.

Seems like hudi ignores the second part of the composite primary key when applying deletion.

What am I missing?